# Merge API into one and select using SQL

Tags: php, sql

So I have been trying to combine the json data from 2 URL so and select them using SQL statements. I tried to combine them but no vail. But if I use the URL separately my code would work and show the data from the URL

This is the example of the URL

```
$url1='https://comp.car';
$url2='https://comp.car2';
```

This is what I tried which I tried to use curl_init and then merge the array:

```
$curl1 = curl_init($url1);
curl_setopt($curl1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$return[] = json_decode(curl_exec($curl1),true);
$data   = [];
curl_close($curl1);


$curl2 = curl_init($url2);
curl_setopt($curl2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$return[] = json_decode(curl_exec($curl2),true);
$data   = [];
curl_close($curl2);

$json = json_encode(array_merge($return ));
```

And this is my SQL statement, which I think might be the reason the code does not work. Both of the URL have different variable.

```
while(count($return) > $count)
{
 
        
    if($dtID == 'compound')
    {
    
                $sql    .= "SELECT      '".$return[$count]['NUMBER']."'   AS NUMBER,
                            CONCAT_WS('<br>', '".$return[$count]['ID']."', '".$return[$count]['PLATENO']."') AS PLATEID,
                                               
                          
                            '".$return[$count]['MISTAKE']."'              AS MISTAKE,
                            '".$return[$count]['LOCATION']."'        AS LOCATION,
                            '".$return[$count]['PAYMENT']."'            AS PAYMENT,
                            
                            '".$return[$count]['compound_num']."'           AS NUMBER,
                            '".$return[$count]['id']."'           AS PLATEID,                            
                            '".$return[$count]['vehicle_num']."'            AS PLATENUMBER,
                            '".$return[$count]['offence']."'                AS MISTAKE,
                            ''                                              AS LOCATION,
                            '".$return[$count]['amount']."'                 AS PAYMENT
                            
                    FROM    DUAL UNION ";


       
    }
    
     $count++;
}
```

And here is the JSON data from the URL
$url1:

```
[{"MISTAKE":"throw a ball","NUMBER":"12345","ID":"928","PLATENO":"6754","LOCATION":"Hawaii","PAYMENT":"SG567"}]
```

$url2

```
[{"offence":"spit","id":"6789","compound_num":"678","vehicle_num":"9182","amount":"SG800"}]
```

sorry, this is my first time asking a question here. Sorry for my grammar error etc. Thank you for your time

Comment: Why not see what the SQL statement looks like, when that is probably the problem? It is difficult for us to reconstruct it from the code in your question. You can simply echo and inspect it.

Comment: What are you even doing with this SQL query? It's just selecting fixed values? This code makes no sense.